# .htaccess to directory with masking

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal-7

I'm trying to create an .htaccess redirect from the root to a directory called /newdrupal7site

Here is what I've got:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ newdrupal7site [L]
```

This works, but the /newdrupal7site is showing up in the URL and I can't seem to remove it. I also don't want it to show when you go to pages on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl:

```
RewriteEngine On

# push requests for site to new dir
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://yoursite/newdrupal7site/
ProxyPassReverse / http://yoursite/newdrupal7site/
<Proxy />
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

# redirect base requests
RewriteRule ^/newdrupal7site/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```